# What is the opposite of Ruby's include?

Tags: ruby, reflection

If I have a class instance, containing several included modules, can I dynamically un-include a specific module (In order to replace it)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

No. You can't un-include a mixin in the Ruby *Language*. On some Ruby *Implementations* you can do it by writing an implementation specific extension in C or Java (or even Ruby in the case of Rubinius), though.

Answer (score 6):

It's not *really* the same thing, but you can fake it with something like this:

```
module A
  def hello
    puts "hi!"
  end
end

class B 
  include A
end

class C
  include A
end

B.new.hello # prints "Hi!"

class Module
  def uninclude(mod)
    mod.instance_methods.each do |method|
      undef_method(method)
    end
  end
end

class B
  uninclude A
end

B.new.hello rescue puts "Undefined!" # prints "Undefined!"
C.new.hello  # prints "Hi!"
```

This may work in the common case, but it can bite you in more complicated cases, like where the module inserts itself into the inheritance chain, or you have other modules providing methods named the same thing that you still want to be able to call. You'd also need to manually reverse anything that `Module.included?(klass)` does.

Comment: `remove_method` (instead of `undef_method`) removes it from the module, instead of blocking the whole chain, so it would allow overridden methods to be un-overridden

Answer (score 4):

Try http://github.com/yrashk/rbmodexcl, which provides an `unextend` method for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Mixology C extension (for MRI and YARV): http://www.somethingnimble.com/bliki/mixology

Answer (score 1):

If you have already `include`-ed something, you can use `load` to re-include the file.  Any definitions in the `load`-ed file will overwrite existing methods.

Answer (score 0):

the true answer is refinement

please check this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19462745/1409600