# Ruby & Modularization - Are there any clean & easy ways to exclude included||extended modules/mixins from classes?

Tags: ruby, module, multiple-inheritance, modularity, mixins

Stackoverflowers!

I've recently begun dabbling in Ruby, and I have a few questions. First some background: I'm used to C++ and Java inheritance, and have always had a dislike for how inheritance works there in many game-related scenarios (say, a roguelike, for example). Mainly due to it being hard to encapsulate behaviour in a good way. For examples, in Java: (not that I'd implement it this way, but it was the best example I could come up with on short notice.)

```
Actor extends GameObject
Creature extends Actor

FlyingCreature extends Creature
Dragon extends FlyingCreature

Humanoid extends Creature
```

...so far so good, right? But what if I decided to implement a class "Gargoyle" (winged humanoid)? Then it would belong to both FlyingCreature and Humanoid -- so I'd have to encapsulate one of the traits and then refactor it or something.

The ideal solution -- personally -- would be if there were some effective way to extract the unique attributes/functionality into encapsulated objects, and then have every GameObject be a composition of different modularized components that can interact with each other. (With no inheritance besides eventualities such as Item:GameObject, Actor:GameObject, Tile:GameObject -- if even then).

So that a specific GameObject (say, an orc) can be easily created by kinda creating a tree of components -- something crudely like this but more flexible:

```
          [Actor]
[Organic]/  |    \[Persona] // Name, etc..
            |          \
       [Humanoid]      [Intelligence] // AI or PlayerController
            |
       [Inventory] // [ArrayList of items...]
            |
       [Equipment] // [Hash of :slot -> Item]
```

But more to the point: As I started learning about Ruby, I learned about it's meta-programming abilities, it's runtime freedom due to the language's reflection, and the extend/include capabilities of modules. So I figured that if I divided specific traits into modules (and made sure to have careful naming policies and such), then I could allow my classes to include behaviour according to context and events. For example, let's say I have a dwarf -- named Bob O'Copp -- and he trips on a tiny vampire piglet while spelunking in some dark sewer dungeon. And thus he falls into some magichemical puddle that mutates him -- giving him cute fairy wings. But since dwarves aren't normally avian, his class wouldn't have the functionality of flight. But for this instance, it would be a valid trait. Thus, I figured that "bob.extend Flight" would be an excellent solution to the issue.

But what if one of the traits is temporal? Let's say Bob O'Copp finds a scroll that summons magical wings on his back for the duration of the spell... But. After a lot of googling I've yet to find any good information as to how to retract/un-extend nor exclude mixins after it's been applied -- if at all practically possible. And since there's a lot of really smart and experienced programmers here, so I'd like to formally implore you to bestow some of your magnificent insight, O mighty bearded oracles! :-)

So... a few questions:

- Am I delusional to want to use mixins this way?
- Is there some big drawback I haven't thought of?
- Is it at all possible to retract a mixin once applied?
- Do you have any other recommendations for a good way to deal with the issue? (giving me a direction in the form of some keywords would sufficient)

Eagerly awaiting any replies with anticipation

Great thanks in advance,

-Robocopulate

Comment: See also [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403057/how-can-i-reverse-rubys-include-function) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088211/what-is-the-opposite-of-rubys-include).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Am I delusional to want to use mixins this way?***
I don't think that you are delusional. Temporary mixins sounds like a neat way to describe your goals.

***Is there some big drawback I haven't thought of?***
Not that is obvious to me after a short bit of reflection, except (see next question)…

***Is it all possible to retract a mixin once applied?***
Not in unmodified Ruby. There are various proposals for adding `unextend` or similar, but none have yet been added to the official language.

However, there is the [Remix](https://github.com/banister/remix) library, which gives you both `unextend` and `temp_include` and more. If you're going to run somewhere that Remix is available, you can use that.

***Do you have any other recommendations for a good way to deal with the issue?***
You could always roll your own inheritance system. :| For example, create module functions that accept an instance to operate upon (possibly using `instance_eval` to violate its encapsulation and store custom data) and then keep track of whether or not a particular module is available.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much for a very quick and insightful answer. The plan was to hobby code a small game to improve my grasp on the language, so Remix sounds like an excellent idea. I'll make sure to check it out, but first I'll give your other recommendation a shot since seems like an excellent exercise to learn more about Ruby. Bummer that I can't give you more than +1! :-)