# Ruby 2.0 How do I uninclude a module out from a module after including it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

```
module X
end

module Y
end

module Z
  #TODO include X replacement of including Y
  #TODO include Y replacement of including X
end
```

Is there a way to work around the fact that ruby contains no uninclude keyword??

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the opposite of Ruby's include?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088211/what-is-the-opposite-of-rubys-include)

Comment: @LoganSerman ruby 2.0 answer I seek

Comment: *include X replacement of including Y* means ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit remove Y from the ancestors chain when including X and viceversa

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really need this kind of functionality, you could probably do it by using [refinements](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html).

```
class Foo
end

module X
  def x
    puts 'x'
  end
end

module Y
end

module R
  refine Foo do
    include X
    include Y
  end
end

# In a separate file or class
using R
# Foo now includes X and Y
Foo.new.x

# In a different file or class
# Foo no longer includes X and Y
Foo.new.x # NoMethodError
```

Answer (score 1):

The genuine answer is that in Ruby, be it 1.x or 2.x, there is *no way* to uninclude a module once included. But I know that someone, somewhere has written Ruby extension that allows unincluding modules.

EDIT: OK, actually, OP is the duplicate of [What is the opposite of Ruby's include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088211/what-is-the-opposite-of-rubys-include), so according to its answer by [@eliah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165065/eliah) and [banister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66725/banister) the libraries in question are https://github.com/yrashk/rbmodexcl and https://github.com/banister/mixology19

Comment: Boris its too old same as mixology - expect issues & I'm not up to C challenges, I'm checkin davogones & cary answers, load is smart solution, refinement is cleaner. if refinement worked for me, definitely will let the world know that it is needed!

Comment: You are absolutely right. I have not tried those libraries. I think that there must be a reason why Matz did not provide this functionality in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too happy with this, but it does work if both modules contain the same method names.

file c.rb

```
module A
  def me
    puts "I am C"
  end
  def whosit?
    puts "It's me, Becky"
  end
end
```

file d.rb

```
module A
  def me
    puts "I am D"
  end
end
```

Then

```
class X
  load('c.rb')
  include A
end

x = X.new

x.me # => I am C
x.whosit? # => It's me, Becky
load('d.rb')
x.me # => I am D
x.whosit? # => It's me, Becky !! Unwanted !!
load('c.rb')
x.me # => I am C
```

`load()` is just opening module A and changing and/or adding code; anything there that it does not touch remains.  `load()` is not real bright.  I think it basically does an `eval()` and could care less if it loads the same file more than once.

To use this, do not also `require` c.rb or d.rb.

Edit: In an earlier edit I added an observation about `require_relative`.  On reflection, I see it was neither relevant nor interesting, so off with its head.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a class that can dynamically choose whether or not to include a module, you can achieve that by including the module on the singleton class during initialization.

That won't get you the same thing as "unincluding" the module on one object's singleton class while keeping included on the class itself (which is what comes to mind for me with `uninclude`), but it may match some features of the refinement solution above (that has the same issue) with a different pattern if that sparks some ideas for you.

```
module A
  def hi; :hi; end
end

class Foo
  def initialize(include_a = true)
    singleton_class.include(A) if include_a
  end
end

Foo.new.hi
# => :hi

Foo.new(false).hi
# NoMethodError: undefined method `hi' for #<Foo:0x00007fe19a973f00>
```

Understand that this is an old question, but if you're looking around for `uninclude` functionality, it's worth really thinking about what precisely you're trying to do with it - is something like "dynamic inclusion" enough?