# Redefining class in Ruby seems to include wrong module

Tags: ruby, class, module, include

I come from a Python background, and I was trying to understand how Ruby includes compare to Python's multiple inheritance. Specifically, I was setting up two modules with the same method to see how `super` work.

I included `Mod`, then `Mod2`, then `Mod` again. However, `A` still seems to be referencing `Mod2`.

```
module Mod
  def foo(x)
    x**2
  end
end
module Mod2
  def foo(x)
    x*2
  end
end

class A
  include Mod
  def foo(x)
    super(x) + 1
  end
end
A.new.foo(5) == 26 # true

class A
  include Mod2
  def foo(x)
    super(x) + 1
  end
end
A.new.foo(5) == 11 # true

class A
  include Mod
  def foo(x)
    super(x) + 1
  end
end
A.new.foo(5) == 26 # false. Is 11
```

Why isn't the third `A.new.foo(5)` return `26`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you may be missing is that the second `class A ... end` is not redefining the class, it's adding to it. You’re allowed to "open" a class multiple times in ruby and (re-)define whatever you want. That, and what you seem to have already figured out, which is that `include` more or less just drops the code from the module into that spot in the class definition, unless that module has already been included in which case it does nothing.

You can do this with any class at all (whether advisable or not)

```
class Hash
  def to_a
    'lol you probably wanted an array here'
  end
end
{foo: :bar}.to_a # Returns above string instead of [:foo, :bar]
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining `class A(object)` in PythonCreates an object with a `type` of `type` and `__name__` of `A`, then assigns that object to the label `A`. A second `class A(object)` definition creates a whole new `type` object that is then put into label A.

Classes in ruby aren't stored in labels, and they can be opened to add more functionality. A good example of this is `2.days`. Rails defines `days` on integer. Without Rails, `2.days` fails.

The 3 class definitions above are roughly equivalent to:

```
class A
  include Mod
  def foo(x)
    super(x) + 1
  end

  include Mod2
  def foo(x)
    super(x) + 1
  end

  include Mod
  def foo(x)
    super(x) + 1
  end
end
```

When ruby sees the second `include Mod`, it knows `Mod` has already been included on the class and skips it, leaving `foo` from `Mod2` as the most recent definition.

If you remove `foo` from later definitions, `A` still has access to it:

```
class A
  include Mod
  def foo(x)
    super(x) + 1
  end
end
A.new.foo(5) == 26 # true

class A
  include Mod2
end
A.new.foo(5) == 11 # true

class A
  include Mod
end
A.new.foo(5) == 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby finds `super` by searching the class/module's ancestry chain one class/module at a time until it finds the definition of the method it's looking for. Sort of like a bus with many stops, looking for the right place to get off, but it always gets off at the first opportunity. If it gets all the way up to `BasicObject` and doesn't find it's stop it will raise a `NoMethodError`.

When you include a module, you're adding it to the ancestry chain just above the including class/module. You can find the ancestors, in order, by calling `Module.ancestors`.You can include the same module many times, but it will only be added to the ancestry chain once. Consider this:

```
module Mod
  def foo(x)
    x**2
  end
end

module Mod2
  def foo(x)
    x*2
  end
end

class A
  include Mod
  def foo(x)
    super(x) + 1
  end
end

A.ancestors # => [A, Mod, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

class A
  include Mod2
  def foo(x)
    super(x) + 1
  end
end

A.ancestors # => [A, Mod2, Mod, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

class A
  include Mod
  def foo(x)
    super(x) + 1
  end
end

A.ancestors # => [A, Mod2, Mod, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

`Mod` was already in the ancestry chain the second time it was included, so nothing new happened. It stays put, and `super` still hits `Mod2` first. In short, you can't "override" newer modules by including older modules that were already there. There are other things you can do though. You could define a `Mod3`, or maybe `ModOverride`, with the same definition of `foo` as was in `Mod` and include that, or look into refinements [Ruby 2.0 How do I uninclude a module out from a module after including it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461978/ruby-2-0-how-do-i-uninclude-a-module-out-from-a-module-after-including-it)

### Side note

As other answers noted, you don't need to redefine `A#foo` every time if the definition is staying the same.