# Can I override an include directive in a class?

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby class that looks like this:

```
class X
  include SomeModule
end
```

Can I override this `X` class so as to not include `SomeModule`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby 2.0 How do I uninclude a module out from a module after including it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461978/ruby-2-0-how-do-i-uninclude-a-module-out-from-a-module-after-including-it)

Comment: Is this something you would want to do (if so, why?), or are you just curious?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought though. If you don't meed SomeModule you can code such that you only include when it *is* needed.

```
class X
  if really_need_some_module
    include SomeModule
  end
end
```

The code in a class definition is *running* Ruby code! You can make choices. That way you avoid including it when it is not needed.

Thus no need for backsies or un-include.

Comment: "Thus no need for backsies or un-include" - Except when the code in question comes from a gem or something like that.

Comment: Yes, like what @SergioTulentsev suggests, the include is inside a gem, so I can't really change the original code for the class, only override it.

Comment: Fair enough but this was not mentioned in your post or indicated in your sample code.